# Filtering in QGIS attribute table similar to dropdown in Excel

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector, excel, filter

I have a large amount of point data that has so far been managed in an Excel list. In the future, these should be shown in QGIS.

To convince colleagues of this, I am looking for a way to make filtering this data as easy as it is in Excel. Using the clickable query creation, you do not necessarily have to write SQL queries yourself, but it is still not as easy as the drop-down menus in Excel (see picture).

[image: example]

Is there another way, or a helpful plugin, that can make filtering a little easier?

Comment: You could create separate layers for each commodity group?

Comment: Or rule based styling or classification

Comment: I've already thought of that, but the possible queries are too individual for that.

Comment: Not exactly, what you are looking for, but have you checked out the **GroupStats** Plug-In? It allows shuffeling data from the attribute table similar to the Pivot-Table function in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of the functionality exactly as friendly as the checkboxes in Excel, but you could try creating a brief dummy guide on how to write an expression to select features using simple conditions? There's a selection filter button on top in the attribute table (see screenshot below):

[image]

It requires appropriate inputs, but perhaps your future users could be still shown this?

Plus, keep in mind that working with the attribute table if there are a lot of rows/features will be slow and the screen might "stuck" as the observations are being filtered - so might be worth alerting your future users about this behavior.